# CodeIgniter constructor is not work proper

Tags: codeigniter

```
class model_demo extends CI_Model{
function model_demo()
  {
    parent::Model();
  }
}
```

I'm working with CodeIgniter with a constructor, and it's producing a fatal error.

Comment: You need to research more. Try to look in the CodeIgniter manual first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class model_demo extends CI_Model{
function model_demo()
{ 
   parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Codeigniter 2 or abore, try:

```
class model_demo extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();        
    }
}
```

You can see the syntax here:

[Models: Codeigniter User guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)